# Insert different prefixes to alternating lines of a file

Tags: file, unix

I'm having trouble creating 2 commands that insert one word (different between the commands) at the beginning of every line with step = 2.

For example:

Before:
10
10
10
10

After:
group1 10
group2 10
group1 10
group2 10

So what I would want is that 1 command starts inserting the word 'group1' to every odd line, while the second command inserts the word 'group2 to every even.

The number 10 is chosen randomly as a substitute for my data numbers

Hope you could help me with this.

Cheers,

Comment: This question, at least to me, isn't clear!

Comment: I refined my question. Hope this'll help you to understand what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Do you simply want to *print* this output or do you want to prepend data to lines in a file?

Comment: I would want to prepend group1 and group2 to every line in a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with sed, here handling odd and even lines separately:

```
sed '1~2 s/^/group1 /' original.txt | sed '2~2 s/^/group2 /' >modified.txt
```

The 1~2 matches every second line starting with first, and 2~2 matches every second line starting from second. "s" substitutes, "^" matches the start of the line